# React app routing with express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am making react app and I want to use express server for backend because I want to have user authentication and registration.

So is it reasonable to create couple of "apps" signIn, signUp and general app where user data is displayed. If yes how is it possible to route these different apps for express server? As I have understood is that express serves only index.html of react and browser makes the rest necessary file requests.

Comment: You shouldn't create multiple apps to handle registration and signing in. It should all be one app. The routing should be handled client-side with react-router-dom. Each route should display a separate component (Login, Register). Express will always only serve up the index.html file of the one app.

Comment: I think Austris might be describing API endpoints perhaps when he meant couple of apps??  and probably wants to use backend for signup/registration and react for rest of it.  is that right Austris?

Comment: There is no separate Apps, it is weary confusing about how to route react application, but I have looked up in some forums and videos with explanations how to do routing in react and I think I will stick to react-router-dom.

Comment: @Austris, what kind of authentication are you looking for? Google OAuth?